# How to iterate json array using pug?

Tags: javascript, pug

I need to iterate through a json array using pug.

By using this route

```
app.get('/drone', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(mqttClient.drone_gps_json)
    res.render('drone', {
        title: 'drone',
        message: (mqttClient.drone_gps_json)
    });
})
```

I'm having this output

```
[
  '{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [5.068762643835973, 4.348367550295752]}',
  '{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [5.230064273129623, 4.0352242534817835]}',
  '{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [4.724948591970712, 4.93405260010674]}',
  '{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [4.177566385080386, 5.875375587957874]}',

   ... 

]
```

To visualize the json array I used this pug file:

```
html
    head
        title= title
    body
        h1= message
```

It works

However, I would like to have a bullet list like:

```
* "type": "Point", "coordinates": [5.068762643835973, 4.348367550295752]
* "type": "Point", "coordinates": [5.230064273129623, 4.0352242534817835]
* ...
```

As already suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52470000/iterate-over-javascript-object-in-pug) I tried with:

```
html
    head
        title= title
    body
        ul
            each item in message
                li= message
```

But I'm having this error:

```
GET /drone 500 211.871 ms - 1111
Error: Failed to lookup view "error" in views directory "/webserver/views"
```

suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have problems because the request output is a **list of strings** that looks like JSON. But it is not a **list of objects** as it may looks.

You can use [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) to convert a string into a json object. You can also use the [map method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to apply JSON.parse on every string of the array.

Here is an example :

```js
var resp = [
  '{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [5.068762643835973, 4.348367550295752]}',
  '{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [5.230064273129623, 4.0352242534817835]}',
  '{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [4.724948591970712, 4.93405260010674]}',
  '{"type": "Point", "coordinates": [4.177566385080386, 5.875375587957874]}'
] ;

var formattedArr = resp.map( str => JSON.parse(str) );

console.log("list of strings : ",resp);
console.log("list of objects : ", formattedArr);
```

I don't know if that can resolve your problem. Hope it help ;)